# Get the most common values for all columns

Tags: mysql

I want to get the most common values for all columns in a mySQL table.

```
[id]  [UserID]            [UserID2]
1     johnnietheblack     marywhite
2     johnnietheblack     marywhite
3     dannyrottenegg      dannyrottenegg     
4     marywhite           marywhite
5     marywhite           johnnietheblack     
6     johnnietheblack     marywhite
```

Here's the output I want:

```
[id]  [UserID]            [Count]
    1     johnnietheblack     4
    2     dannyrottenegg      2
    3     marywhite           6
```

I can use the following to get the common values for one columns. But how can I get the common values for **all columns**?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Rows`, UserID
FROM table-name
GROUP BY UserID
ORDER BY `Rows` DESC
```

Comment: I'm not clear enough, can you explain different? what do you expected to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT UserID, COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT UserID FROM tablename
 UNION ALL
 SELECT UserID2 FROM tablename) t
GROUP BY UserID
```

I didn't include the `id` column because it doesn't seem to correlate with the values.

If you want to see all of the ids for each name, you can use GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id), UserID, COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT id, UserID FROM tablename
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id, UserID2 FROM tablename) t
GROUP BY UserID
```

Comment: _Error: Every derived table must have its own alias_

Comment: Thank you, now it works. I tried to add the id column too before _COUNT_ but it returns an error. Where should I put it?

Comment: @WeContest, The values for the id column would be arbitrary. What do you want id for?

Comment: Is not possible to use original ids?

Comment: @WeContest, johnnietheblack shows up on 4 different records. Which id do you want to see? If you want to see them all, use `GROUP_CONCAT(id)`, otherwise, you must specify which one you want.

Comment: I've tried to put _GROUP_CONCAT(id)_ before _COUNT_, but it returns an error.