# Get the 5 most common usernames in table

Tags: mysql

someone who knows how I can get the 5 most common strings in my MySQL database?

I want the most 2 common usernames which are used on my honeypot and display them in descending (so most common first) in a small HTML table.

MySQL table: honeypot
table column: user

my table looks like this:

```
[attempt_ID]    [user]    [password]
1               Foo           Bar
2               Bar           Foo
3               Foo           Test
4               Bar           Foo
5               Foo           Nyancat123
6               Bar           DikkeBMW
7               Foo           Password
8               John          Doe
```

all I want is the usernames, not the password.
and I think it should look something like this:

```
[user]   [count]
Foo      4
Bar      3
```

I've already looked at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160532/get-the-most-common-values-for-all-columns) Thread, but I couldn't make anything out of it as I don't know MySQL that well...

Comment: `select user, count(*) as total from table_name group by user order by total desc limit 2`

Comment: That did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Assuming common `user_name` at least have count >1

```
select user_name,count(*) as count from tbl
group by user_name having count>1 order by count desc limit 5;
```

Comment: Not entirely correct, see first comment under the question.

Comment: no, is entirely correct, re-read that first comment it includes an order. limit 5 is not guaranteed to produce the wanted 5 unless you use order by

Answer (score 0):

it returns 5 users which occurred maximum times.

```
SELECT user_name,COUNT(1) AS count_user 
FROM table
GROUP BY user_name 
ORDER BY count_user DESC
LIMIT 5;
```